# Flutter with Supabase not changing state when running in release mode

Tags: flutter, supabase

i want to ask about my Flutter app problem. In my app, i use `flutter_bloc` for state management (generated with `very_good_cli`) and `supabase_flutter` for the database. In debug mode its runs fine. But when I run with the release flag, the app is not changing and stuck in the Loading state (as it is the first state after login). I use realtime function in Supabase and fetch it with Stream like this,

`_client.from(tableName).stream(primaryKey: ['id']).eq('id', id)`

I've tried to edit some of the gradle file configurations like disabling minify and shrink resources. Resulted in the same as previous.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same with Supabase. My login worked fine in debug but not in release.

Adding Internet permission in the manifest file solved this issue for me.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```